# Clarification of a proof that $x^2$ is continuous everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

So I've been looking at the proof for this question and was wondering if some one could help me walk through the reasoning or could look through my proof.

> We fix $\epsilon >0$, and observe that $|x^2 -c^2|= |x-c||x+c|$. Suppose that $\delta < 1$ so that $|x-c| < \delta < 1$.

(First I want to discuss this assumption - my understanding is that we can make this assumption because if in reality $\delta \geq 1$, a smaller $\delta$ will always 'fit'. I.e. then, $|x-c| < 1 \Rightarrow |x-c| < \delta$, so this assumption is safe. Is this reasonable?)

> Next, we observe $|x+c| = |x-c+2c| \leq |x-c| + 2|c| < 1 + 2|c|$ 
>   Thus using difference of two squares I can say that:
>   $|x^2-c^2| < \epsilon$
>   and that
>   $|x^2-c^2| = |x-c||x+c| < \delta (1+2|c|)$

Here I want to ask, what is the relation between $\epsilon$ and $\delta (1+2|c|)$, and why. I've seen answers stating that $\epsilon$ is greater but I can't why this is the case.

> From here they generally conclude that we take $\delta$ to be the smaller of $\frac{\epsilon}{1+2|c|}$ and $1$.

But if the latter, doesn't this feel contradictory given our assumtion that $\delta < 1$ Or are we simply saying that such a value of $\delta$ is 'sufficient'. From my understanding our logic here is that we need to satisfy both conditions we placed on $\delta$ thus we set it to be the smallest?

Comment: "In reality" is the wrong way to think of it. The $\delta$ is not defined by the definition of continuity, it is found. So you put the conditions on $\delta$ you need. Here, you need $\delta<1$ to make your proof, so you add that condition.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. My understanding is that we are given an arbitrary $\epsilon$ and we need to bound |x-c|. My interpretation is that for larger $\epsilon$, delta has more flexibility, but we want more precision so we lock $\delta <1$, with the understanding that small $\delta$ will still satisfy the larger $\epsilon$. 

Am I correct in saying that I could infact set $\delta$ < k, where k is any number greater than 0, and still conduct the same proof? As in the choice of 1 is arbitrary as well?

Comment: One the last question: Yes, if they take $\delta =\min(\dots,1)$ then it is not true that $\delta<1$. Instead, they should say $\delta=\min(\dots,1/2)$, or "Pick $\delta<\min(\dots,1)$." I'm not sure "generally conclude" is true. You'd have to give me a few examples to support that.

Comment: There is no one delta, so "in reality, $\delta>1$" is not a meaningful statement. There is no one "real" $\delta$. You are trying to find a $\delta$.

Comment: You don't need to find all $\delta$ with the property, only one...

Comment: Note that what you really need is $|x-c|<1$. So $\delta=1$ actually isn't a problem, since if $\delta=1$, it is still true that $|x-c|<1$. But again, you seem to be paraphrasing a sloppy argument. Hard to tell why you think this is the general sort of argument. All the errors you've found in this hypothetical argument are easily fixed.

Comment: Okay, so the argument goes that we want to find any $\delta$ that as long as x is within, f(x) will be within $\epsilon$ of f(c). It's generally the case that  small $\epsilon$ leads to a smaller set of $\delta$, right? But even in large $\epsilon$ we can use small $\delta$ so Its always the case there is some $\delta <1$ that satisfies the conditions.

So we can proceed here with our argument, and later on with our two conditions on $|x-c|$ we set $\delta$ to be the lower one, as it satisfies both conditions, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

The key is really that the first part of the proof really isn't the proof. It's just giving a way to find the proof.

The actual proof is:

> Given $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta=\min\left(\frac{\epsilon}{1+2|c|},1\right).$
>   Then if $|x-c|<\delta$ we have:
>   $$ |x-c|<\delta\leq \frac{\epsilon}{1+2|c|}\\
> |x+c|\leq |x-c| + 2|c|<\delta+2|c|\leq 1+2|c|$$
>   So:
>   $$|x^2-c^2|=|x-c||x+c|< \frac{\epsilon}{1+2|c|} \cdot \left(1+2|c|\right)=\epsilon$$

There is a tendency to write these proofs in reverse, to explicate *how* you got the component conditions for $\delta$. But that is not necessary[*], it is just exposition for learning purposes, not a natural part of the proof.

As you can see, we are using both conditions, and it is quite clear what both conditions are doing. We are trying to bound a product by bounding the two factors. The second line is not bounded if you don't put an *additional* bound on $\delta$.

[*] Not necessary as part of a formal proof, but it might be preferred on homework, because it is like "showing your work" in a computation.

By the way, you could rewrite the proof as:

> Given $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta=\min\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\pi+2|c|},\pi\right).$
>   Then if $|x-c|<\delta$ we have:
>   $$ |x-c|<\delta\leq \frac{\epsilon}{\pi+2|c|}\\
> |x+c|\leq |x-c| + 2|c|<\delta+2|c|\leq \pi+2|c|$$
>   So:
>   $$|x^2-c^2|=|x-c||x+c|< \frac{\epsilon}{\pi+2|c|} \cdot \left(\pi+2|c|\right)=\epsilon$$

The number $1$ is a red herring. You could have picked *any* positive value initially to bound $|x+c|$, as long as you change the second bound, as well. The number $1$ is just the easiest positive number to write.

There is no one "right" $\delta$.

Comment: Thank you! I apologise that the proof I gave sounded paraphrased, I generally learn things by paraphrasing the points in the proof so they seem intuitive, but it appears I may have missed out certain points (on top of slight sloppiness in the proof I read).

Comment: Well, if you are objecting to a particular proof technique, it is better to get the details right. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without saying anything else, you first assume $\delta<1$. You need not to say anything about this than just saying this is an assumption. After all, you are required to find some $\delta$ when you are given some $\varepsilon>0$.

Now assuming $\delta<1$, you found that

$$
|x^2-c^2|<\delta (1+2|c|)
$$

Now since $c$ is fixed, $(1+2|c|)$ is a fixed constant, and since we are given $\varepsilon>0$, then clearly $\displaystyle \frac{\varepsilon}{1+2|c|}$ is a fixed postive constant.

Therefore, at least one of

$$
1>\frac{\varepsilon}{1+2|c|} \;\;\; \text{or} \;\;\; 1\le \frac{\varepsilon}{1+2|c|}
$$

happens, so the quantity $\delta=\min\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{1+2|c|}\}$ is well defined. Then naturally $\delta\le 1$, and so as you've shown in this case

$$
|x^2-c^2|\le\delta (1+2|c|) \le \frac{\varepsilon}{1+2|c|} (1+2|c|) = \varepsilon
$$